# CloudFront multi site based on paths / routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-cloudfront

### Existing App

I have a website hosted on S3 and CloudFront. APIs are hosted on ECS and are served by CloudFront via `/api/*` Behaviour. To handle the manual entered routes I've configured Error Pages 404 and 403 to route to /index.html on Default Behaviour.

```
URL         -> CF -> S3 (default origin)
URL/api/**  -> CF -> LB -> ECS+Fargate
```

### Requirement

What I'm trying to do is host **Admin** site under a new path /admin pointing to new S3 bucket (origin 3).

```
URL/admin    -> CF -> S3 (Origin 3)
```

### Problem

All the traffic at /admin path is falling under Error pages and is getting routed to  Default origin.

**Things I've checked:**

1. There are no conflicting paths
2. Cleared Cache
3. S3 configs are exactly same on Default Origin Bucket and Origin 3 Bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution when I removed the Error pages config. After removing this config, I was getting `Access Denied` error. This is the error when really the access is not there OR when the object doesn't exists. So it seems that CloudFront was unable to access files on S3 bucket.

The solution was that `/admin/` path require `admin` folder in s3 as well for both paths to map on each other. When I moved my files in 2nd S3 bucket in correct folder everything started working.

This is a great way to host 2 sites which can share the Cookies and FrontEnd context with each other as both are under the same domain. And you don't need to manage CORS as well for this.